# Parameter 3 of constructor in required a bean of type 'package' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans

I have call method which is defined in NoteService interface, the implementation of this method is in NoteImpl class. I am trying to access this method from Refresh class, but I am getting this error

```
Parameter 3 of constructor in com.new.macro.rest.Refresh required a bean of type 'com.new.macro.unity.processorService' that could not be found.
Action:Consider defining a bean of type 'com.new.macro.unity.NoteService' in your configuration.
```

I need help resolving this error.

Here is my Refresh class from where I try to access `call` method from `NoteImpl class`

```
package com.new.macro.rest;
@Component
public class Refresh implements BaseService {

    private final NoteService<Inbuild> iNoteService;

    public Refresh(final NoteService iNoteService) {
        this.iNoteService = iNoteService;
    }

    @PUT
    public String firstRefresh() {
        iNoteService.call(Types);
        return RefreshStatus.STARTED.toJsonResponse();
    }
```

Here is NoteImpl class with `call method functionality`

```
@Configuration
public abstract class NoteImpl implements NoteService{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(NoteImpl.class);

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private final String Url;


    public NoteImpl( RestTemplate restTemplate,@Value("${url}") String Url){
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        this.Url = Url;
    }

    public void call(Set<Inbuild> Types, String Url) {

        Set<String> results = new HashSet<>();
        \\ Remaining functionality
    }
}
```

Here is the interface

```
package com.new.macro.unity;


import java.util.Set;


public interface NoteService<T> {

    void call(Set<? extends T> Types);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all these classes are classpath scanned:
- `NoteImpl` shouldn't be abstract
- `NoteImpl` should be annotated as `@Component` instead of `@Configuration`. Configuration classes are the ones that create beans

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Autowired` annotation on head of constructor:

```
@Autowired
public Refresh(final NoteService iNoteService) {
    this.iNoteService = iNoteService;
}
```

Then you will get a bean from `NoteService`.

Comment: It is giving same error. Any other suggestions? Is is something to do with my logic of accessing the method?

Comment: Add the same on `NoteImpl` on it head `@Autowired public NoteImpl( RestTemplate restTemplate,@Value("${url}") String Url)`

Comment: Same error, further checking this error `AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'refresh' defined in file [Refresh.class]: Unsatisfied dependency  through constructor parameter 3; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.new.macro.unity.processorService<?>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. `

Comment: Ok then change `NoteService` to `NoteImpl` as parameter `public Refresh(final NoteImpl iNoteImpl)`

Comment: I did that now it says required  a bean of type NoteImpl

Comment: Yes, also you should add what I mentioned before about `@Autowired` on `public NoteImpl(...)`  and `public Refresh(...)` as well.

Comment: Seriously stucked at this error for days, tried all the possibilities. Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Hi any suggestions for this qs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59780621/java-how-to-write-junit-tests-for-resttemplate-postforobject . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, don't keep NoteImpl as abstract class - abstract classes can't be instantiated. That should resolve the problem. Though @Configuration will work(as it's meta annotated with @Component), @Service makes sense here.

Also, you don't need @Autowired at constructor injection - that is optional. (So the other answer won't solve the problem)